# error: syntax error at or near "$"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, axios, pg-promise

I am currently checking out Vue and am doing a little refactor on a personal project.

I am running into some problems with my API.

The two technologies involved are [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) which I am using to send requests to my API, which talks to a postgres database using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

The api call...

```
function add (entry, cb) {
  const length = entry.content.length
  entry.title = `${entry.content.substring(0, 32)}`
  axios.post('/api/notes', entry).then(cb)
}
```

here, entry is and **object { title, content, prio, status, context }**

the pg-promise endpoint

```
export const createNote = (req, res, next) => {
  db.none('insert into entries(title, content, prio, status, context)' +
      'values( ${title}, ${content}, ${prio}, ${status}, ${context})',
    req.body)
  .then(() => {
    res.status(200)
    .json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'Inserted one entry'
    })
  }).catch(err => next(err))
}
```

here, req.body is **undefined**

1. I don't know why I am getting undefined.
2. Does this [error log](https://gist.github.com/awitherow/1e0385170376780a3e9a482a2f041d14) help?

I was reading through the documentation at axios and could not seem to find anything wrong with my api call, figured I would post something here.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know your issue, but that `if` statement can just be `entry.title = entry.contnt.substring(0, 32);`, you don't need the `if`.

Comment: I think `'values( ${title}, ${content}, ${prio}, ${status}, ${context})'` should be a template literal (it should use backticks instead of apostrophes).

Comment: Check what resulting query you are executing, either by using [pgp.as.format](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.format) or by logging event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query).

Comment: @loganfsmyth haha :sweat_smile:

Comment: @Gothdo I am not sure, it was working this way before with fetch & not axios.

Comment: @vitaly-t I run `console.log(pgp.as.format('insert into entries(title, content, prio, status, context) values( ${title}, ${content}, ${prio}, ${status}, ${context})', req.body)) ` and get `insert into entries(title, content, prio, status, context) values( ${title}, ${content}, ${prio}, ${status}, ${context})`. It req.body is not even shown here in this string printout?

Comment: @AustinWitherow that doesn't look right. Your output is the original query string, before formatting, but it is supposed to be a formatted query string. Something else is missing there that you do not show in your code here. You can post it on the project's website on GitHub, I will try and help you diagnose what's wrong there.

Comment: it is kind of a big PR :D the server is build in build & within build I connect the api functions from the server folder.

`build/server/api` is where the function calls to the build/server/queries resides.

`./src/api/notes` is where the api call resides.

https://github.com/awitherow/aether/tree/vue

Comment: @vitaly-t i've got it figured out... it was my fault on the side of not having the bodyparser npm module available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

req.body It has the following structure [{.....}]

for pg-promise need {....}

Solution to the problem req.body[0]

```
 export const createNote = (req, res, next) => {
  db.none('insert into entries(title, content, prio, status, context)' +
      'values( ${title}, ${content}, ${prio}, ${status}, ${context})',
    req.body[0])
  .then(() => {
    res.status(200)
    .json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'Inserted one entry'
    })
  }).catch(err => next(err))
}
```